# Syntax error in C program

Tags: c

```
#include < stdio.h >

int main() {
    char *s;
    s=call();
    printf(s);
}

char* call() {
    return("hello");
}
```

Why these code not working. It's generating an error. How do I make it work?

Comment: What error are you getting?  A compiler error?  A runtime error?  What is the message?

Comment: conflicting types for all this is the error message i see. and why did the question go -1 ? Is the question wrong?

Comment: sorry guys please excuse for the question.sometimes we dont get the answer even though we know what we are doing.sorry but my problem is solved thank you all.

Comment: thanks to the one who upvoted my question.and i request if the question is too sily you can downvote i agree with you.

Comment: Probably got down-voted because people don't like guessing. The exact error message given (by the compiler?) is kind of vital, and you didn't bother to supply it.

Comment: oh sorry from next time i give you the clear view with the errors in my question.Thank you to all again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

- You can't put spaces inside the angle brackets when including a system header (e.g. `#include <stdio.h>`
- You need a prototype for `call()`

Comment: In the absence of a prototype (in C89), the compiler assumes the function returns `int` ... and it complains when assigning that `int` to `s`, a `char*`.